# GCD dispatch_barrier or dispatch_sync?

Tags: grand-central-dispatch

I have some questions about `dispatch_barrier` and `dispatch_sync`.
Here's the code:

```
- (void)addPhoto:(Photo *)photo
{
    if (photo) { // 1
        dispatch_barrier_async(self.concurrentPhotoQueue, ^{ // 2 
            [_photosArray addObject:photo]; // 3
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ // 4
                [self postContentAddedNotification]; 
            });
        });
    }
}

- (NSArray *)photos
{
    __block NSArray *array; // 1
    dispatch_sync(self.concurrentPhotoQueue, ^{ // 2
        array = [NSArray arrayWithArray:_photosArray]; // 3
    });
    return array;
}
```

In `addPhoto` method, it uses `dispatch_barrier_async`. In `photos` method, it uses `dispatch_sync`. Can I replace the `dispatch_barrier_async` into `dispatch_sync`? If yes, is this way popular in practical programming? If no, please tell me why. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, in this example, replacing `dispatch_barrier_async` with `dispatch_sync` will produce unexpected behavior. You have concurrent queue to access to photos - it means, it lets you run several operations simultaneously. It is okay to read `_photosArray` from as many places, as you want in one time. But bad things happens, if you'll try to change its contents, while somebody reads it. Here comes `dispatch_barrier_async` - it lets you, so to say, add "seriality" to concurrent queue. Block dispatched that way will wait, till all other operations stops, starts, and while its execution no one will start no any operations on that queue.

It is classic [Readers-writers problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writers_problem).

Please, feel free to ask, if something left unexplained

**Update 1**

You cannot use `async` functions in `photos` method. 
`dispatch_sync` makes your method wait until task executed.

By numbers I marked execution flow

```
- (NSArray *)photos
{
    __block NSArray *array; //1. Here array is nil
    dispatch_sync(self.concurrentPhotoQueue, ^{ //2. dispatch task and wait it ends execution
        array = [NSArray arrayWithArray:_photosArray]; //3. Array filled with photos
    });

    return array; //4. Array filled with photos
}
```

If you use `async`

```
- (NSArray *)photos
{
    __block NSArray *array; //1. Here array is nil
    dispatch_async(self.concurrentPhotoQueue, ^{ //2. dispatch task and move on
        array = [NSArray arrayWithArray:_photosArray]; //4. Array filled with photos
    });

    return array; //3. Array is still nil
}
```

**Update 2**

Several `dispatch_sync` calls will run simultaneously.

For example, you have *thread1* and *thread2*. They hold the same object *object*. In some place they simultaneously makes call

*thread1* : `NSLog(@"%@", [object photos]);`
  *thread2* : `NSArray *photos = [object photos];`

This calls will be performed concurrently (i. e. in the same time), but synchronously - threads freeze  till they get photos.

However, if you make something like this

*thread2* : `NSArray *photos = [object addPhoto:newPhoto];`
  *thread1* : `NSLog(@"%@", [object photos]);`

your *thread1* freezes until photo added to an array. But, *thread2* will not wait, till photo actually added - it just continue execution.

Comment: Can I also use `dispatch_barrier_async` in photos method?

Comment: And can I use `dispatch_async` in photos method? I think readers method can be run simultaneously.

Comment: No, you cannot. If you do that, you'll get empty `array` in return. 
See updated anser

Comment: That's great and thanks a lot! I should learn it more carefully! :)

Comment: You're welcome. You should differ serial/concurrent from synchronically/a synchronically. And, don't confuse threads with queues. In GCD you're working with queues and know nothing about threads on which it all actually runs. Take a look at this tutorial http://www.humancode.us/2014/07/31/why-gcd.html. When you'll feel confident, read http://www.humancode.us/2014/08/14/target-queues.html.