# GCD why to use dispatch_sync when I read shared resource

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

I have some question about use `dispatch_sync` when I read a shared resource.
I have searched several questions on Stack Overflow (such as: [GCD dispatch_barrier or dispatch_sync?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32647214/gcd-dispatch-barrier-or-dispatch-sync)), but I didn't found an exact answer.

I don't understand that why to use

```
- (void)addPhoto:(Photo *)photo
{
     if (photo) { // 1
        dispatch_barrier_async(self.concurrentPhotoQueue, ^{ // 2 
            [_photosArray addObject:photo]; // 3
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ // 4
                [self postContentAddedNotification]; 
            });
        });
     }
}

- (NSArray *)photos
{
    __block NSArray *array; // 1
    dispatch_sync(self.concurrentPhotoQueue, ^{ // 2
        array = [NSArray arrayWithArray:_photosArray];
    });
    return array;
}
```

I know why to use `dispatch_barrier_async`,but I don't know why to use dispatch_sync when I read `_photosArray`, I guess the write operation of `_photosArray` is in the `self.concurrentPhotoQueue`, so the read operation of `_photosArray` also need in the `self.concurrentPhotoQueue` or else use `dispatch_sync` in order to achieve multi-read?

What will happen if I don't use `dispatch_sync` when I do read operation? such as:

```
- (NSArray *)photos
{
    __block NSArray *array;
    array = [NSArray arrayWithArray:_photosArray];
    return array;
}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Your implementation of `photos` makes no sense. You create and return a new empty array every it is called. Why? And in `addPhoto:`, what is `_photosArray`?

Comment: this case is copied from this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32647214/gcd-dispatch-barrier-or-dispatch-sync, 
I don't know why to create an NSArray every it is called, and the _photosArray, I guess it is a NSMutableArray. 
the point is that why to use dispatch_sync when I access the _photosArray.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably `concurrentPhotoQueue` is a serial queue. The main reason for `concurrentPhotoQueue` is to synchronize the access to the `photos` array.

Since it is serial all accesses from this queue are serialized, and no race conditions may occur if there are no accesses from other queues / threads in your app.

Writing access may be asynchronous because the writer needs no result of the writing operation in general. But reading must be done synchronously, because the caller has to wait for the result. If your `photos` method would use `dispatch_async` it would write the result to `array` *after* the `photos` method has returned. Thus, `photos` always would return `nil`.

Your unsynchronized version of `photos` might produce a race condition: `_photosArray` could be modified while it copies its contents, such that the number of copied items and the length of the array differ. This could lead to a crash inside of `arrayWithArray:`.

Comment: you said that _photosArray could be modified while it copies its contents, but, the operation of modify _photosArray, is use dispatch_barrier_sync, so that, _photosArray couldn't modified while it copies its contents

Comment: @LeeRQ: Yes, but this only applies to blocks in `concurrentPhotoQueue`. Block from other queues are not blocked by `dispatch_barrier_async`.